# How to get reference as string firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the "RefNegocio" value:
[image: Firestore]

I want it as a string so I can use it to do a query based on that info. If I try to read it like this(empleadoSeleccionado is where all the info is):

```
console.log(empleadoSeleccionado)
```

I get all the info but the ref. I get something like this.

[image: Console log]

This is how I'm reading from firestore

```
useEffect(() => {
    database.collection('EmpleadosDev').get()
        .then(response => {
            const fetchedEmpleados = [];
            const emails = [];
            response.forEach(document => {
                const fetchedEmpleado = {
                    id: document.id,
                    ...document.data()
                };
                fetchedEmpleados.push(fetchedEmpleado);
                fetchedEmpleados.forEach(element => {
                    emails.push(element.Email)
                });
                if (!emails.includes(currentUser.email)) {
                    alert('Este usuario no tiene permisos de acceso. Serás redirigido al login');
                    firebase.auth().signOut();
                    throw BreakException;
                } else {
                    setEmpleadoSeleccionado(fetchedEmpleados[emails.indexOf(currentUser.email)]) //Here I get the value I'm showing
                }
            });
            setEmpleados(fetchedEmpleados);
        })

}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    if (empleadoSeleccionado !== undefined) {
        console.log(empleadoSeleccionado) //Here I'm printing it
    }

}, [empleadoSeleccionado])
```

Comment: The code you shared does not read any data from the database, so it's hard to say where you're going wrong. "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Added some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RefNegocio` field is a document reference, which means that in your code `doc.data().RefNegocio` returns a [`DocumentReference` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference).

To print the path to that document from a `DocumentReference` use:

```
console.log(document.data().RefNegocio.path);
```